# Word matching with dictionaries using R. Analyzing Survey Comments with existing dictionaries

Tags: r, string, text-mining

I'm trying to analyze a list of survey comments with existing word dictionaries in R. Survey comments range from one word to multiple sentences. I have multiple word dictionaries like the ones sampled below. Ideally I would like Column 1 to be survey comments, followed by a column for each dictionary.

The dictionary columns would return a "True" or "False" if a word within the dictionary appears in the survey comment. Some survey comments should have multiple tallies, indicating multiple categories are in the comment.

Survey Comments

```
Survey<- c("Benefits are great", "I like the flexible hours", "my manager is bad", "the manager is great", "my manager gives me flexible hours to work")
```

Dictionaries

```
CompDictionary<- c("benefit", "benefits", "pay")
FlexDictionary<- c("flexible", "flex day", "flex time")
LeadDictionary<- c("manager", "boss", "director")
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated. Let me know if there's anything else I can provide that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your problem as stated, here's a solution using base R.

```
Survey<- c("Benefits are great", "I like the flexible hours", "my manager is bad", "the manager is great", "my manager gives me flexible hours to work")

CompDictionary<- c("benefit", "benefits", "pay")
FlexDictionary<- c("flexible", "flex day", "flex time")
LeadDictionary<- c("manager", "boss", "director")

f = function(dict,Survey){
  apply(do.call(rbind,lapply(dict,grepl,Survey,ignore.case=T)),2,any)
}

res = lapply(list("Comp"=CompDictionary,"Flex"=FlexDictionary,"Lead"=LeadDictionary),f,Survey)

df = as.data.frame(res)
df$Survey = Survey
```

Since you have a list of target words and your survey responses are unprocessed, you would need to use `grepl` which searches for a word and returns a logical TRUE/FALSE if it is present.  However, `grepl` only accepts one input, so we need to `apply` over the list of dictionary terms.  Then we need to check if `any` of them are TRUE.  I wrapped all this up in a function to make calling it later easy.

Now, we need to run that function for each Dictionary. I created a named list (to make the data.frame step easier) and used `lapply` to pass each dictionary into the function I made.  The resulting named list is turned into a data.frame and I append the survey comments.

**Potential Point of Failure**

`grepl` uses regular expressions which is a form of pattern matching. I already set the `ignore.case` flag to TRUE so that 'benefits' will match 'Benefits'.  Still, for more complex matches (e.g. 'flex day') you will only get TRUE on an *exact match* so 'flexible hours' isn't matched by any of your dictionaries right now. So while you have 'benefit' and 'benefits' in your dictionaries (unnecessary in this case) you would have to have 'flexible hour' and 'flex hour' to catch people using the term 'flexible' or 'flex'.

**Things to Consider**

Tokenizing your text and then applying a lemmatizer (or even stemming) could help to reduce variation in terms (making 'flex' and 'flexible' the same word).  This would require that you then learn what the new word is and insert it into your dictionaries.

Comment: Mark, Thank you so much for this reply. I really appreciate the thoroughness and mentions of the potential point of failure. I'm definitely considering tokenizing after your comment. I previously did an LDA on the survey comments to find the topics, then I made the dictionaries based on the words that fit with those topics.  Your response will help immensely for this next step in scaling out the analysis and I greatly appreciate it!